# How to convert text log which contains partially json string to the structured in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to create a data frame from a unstructured logs, which partially contains json

```
2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":-9serverkey,"Type":"status"}
2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:34:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":-9serverkey,"Type":"status"}
2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:35:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":-9serverkey,"Type":"status"}
```

Here what i tried

```
rdd = session.sparkContext.textFile("F:\\mypath\\rdd_test_log.txt")

dataFrame = rdd.map(lambda data: Row(time= data.split(" ")[0],
                                     ip= data.split(" ")[1],
                                     EventTime=data.split(":")[2])).toDF()
```

The result is

```
---------+------------------------+
|EventTime                     |ip       |time                    |
+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
|01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime"|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|
|01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime"|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|
|01.633Z 10.1.20.1 {"EventTime"|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|
+------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

## Expected:

```
time                     |ip        |eventtime          |sourcename|Keys        |Type
2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z |10.1.20.1 |2020-09-24 13:33:01|local     |-9serverkey |status
```

SO how can parse this json string to the rdd? OR what should be the approach?

Appreciated for the help..

Thanks

Comment: First thing first. Work with dataframe : `spark.read.text`. Then, split it into 3 columns, 1 with timestamp, 1 with IP, and 1 with the JSON. You can use the function [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) and limit the number of split with `limit` option. Then, you apply the function [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json).

Comment: `{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":-9serverkey,"Type":"status"}` is not valid JSON. Is that a typo?

Comment: No @Steven.. its not a typo..  the log appeared as it is.. "Keys":-9serverkey .. is there any built in spark sql function to convert to the valid json string ..

Comment: @Adhi Both answer from ernest_k and mine are quite similar. I think they should fix your current issue, just pick the one you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find('{')` on the string to pick up an index from which you can get a substring of the JSON text, then parse that JSON.

```py
dataFrame = (
    rdd.map(lambda l: (l.split(" "), l))
    .map(
        lambda data: Row(
            time=data[0][0], ip=data[0][1], EventTime=data[1][data[1].find("{") :]
        )
    )
    .toDF()
    .select(
        "time",
        "ip",
        f.regexp_replace(f.col("EventTime"), '"Keys":(.*),', '"Keys":"$1",').alias(
            "EventTime"
        ),
    )
)

dataFrame.show(1, False)
```

Shows

```
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|time                    |ip       |EventTime                                                                                    |
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":"-9serverkey","Type":"status"}|
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can parse `EventTime` into a map that can further be spread into many columns:

```py
parsed = dataFrame.select(
    "time",
    "ip",
    f.from_json(
        "EventTime",
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("EventTime", StringType()),
                StructField("sourcename", StringType()),
                StructField("Keys", StringType()),
                StructField("Type", StringType()),
            ]
        ),
    ).alias("eventdetails"),
)
```

Now create separate columns from the map

```py
parsed = (
    parsed.withColumn("eventtime", parsed["eventdetails"].getItem("EventTime"))
    .withColumn("sourcename", parsed["eventdetails"].getItem("sourcename"))
    .withColumn("Keys", parsed["eventdetails"].getItem("Keys"))
    .withColumn("Type", parsed["eventdetails"].getItem("Type"))
    .drop("eventdetails")
)

parsed.show()
```

Which gives:

```
+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
|                time|       ip|          eventtime|sourcename|       Keys|  Type|
+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:33:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:34:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:35:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
```

**Note** that I assumed your JSON is valid. `"Keys":-9serverkey` is an invalid key/value pair, so I edited your data to `"Keys":"-9serverkey"`

Comment: Hi @ernest.. there is issue in json string , as you notified it not a valid .. it appears as "Keys":-9serverkey.. so that the reason the json return null,  as its not a valid.. is there any regular expression can use to make a proper json.. i tried the python regular expression "re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S+)\s*:', r'\n"\1":', data)" from a another function, but it return the error "Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation..'

Comment: @Adhi Edited with a step that cleans up data using `regexp_replace`

Comment: Thanks @Steven.. and ernest.... the issue got resolved..

Answer (score 2):

Replace your RDD with a dataframe and use `text` to acquire your file :

```py
df = spark.read.text("F:\\mypath\\rdd_test_log.txt")

df.show()
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|
+--------------------+
```

then you split and keep your json as text.

```py
# Version Spark >= 3
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("values", F.split(F.col("value"), " ", limit=3)).select(
    F.col("values").getItem(0).alias("time"),
    F.col("values").getItem(1).alias("IP"),
    F.col("values").getItem(2).alias("JSON"),
)

# OR
# Version spark <= 2.4

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

udf_split = F.udf(lambda x : x.split(" ", 2), T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

df = df.withColumn("values", udf_split(F.col("value"))).select(
    F.col("values").getItem(0).alias("time"),
    F.col("values").getItem(1).alias("IP"),
    F.col("values").getItem(2).alias("JSON"),
)

df.show()
+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
|                time|       IP|                JSON|
+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"202...|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"202...|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"202...|
+--------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

Step to fix the json

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "JSON", F.regexp_replace(F.col("JSON"), r'"Keys":([^,]+)', '"Keys":"$1"')
)
df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|time                    |IP       |JSON                                                                                         |
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:33:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":"-9serverkey","Type":"status"}|
|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:34:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":"-9serverkey","Type":"status"}|
|2020-09-24T08:03:01.633Z|10.1.20.1|{"EventTime":"2020-09-24 13:35:01","sourcename":"local","Keys":"-9serverkey","Type":"status"}|
+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then you just have to convert your JSON string to a struct type.

```py
json_struct = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("EventTime", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("sourcename", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("Keys", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("Type", T.StringType()),
    ]
)

df = df.withColumn("JSON", F.from_json("JSON", json_struct))
df.select("time", "IP", "JSON.*").show()

+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
|                time|       IP|          EventTime|sourcename|       Keys|  Type|
+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:33:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:34:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
|2020-09-24T08:03:...|10.1.20.1|2020-09-24 13:35:01|     local|-9serverkey|status|
+--------------------+---------+-------------------+----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Hi Steven.. i am getting the JSON column return  only "{"EventTime":"2020-09-24" not other keys.... it not returning full JSON column value..

Comment: @Adhi Did you miss the `*` ? `"JSON.*"` double quotes JSON point Star double quotes.

Comment: Hi @Steven.. i didn't miss anything as seen.. df.select("time","IP","JSON.*").show(df.count(), False)

Comment: Hi @Steven.. i also noticed that the json string is not valid as it appears from the webserver log... it appear for a string as "Keys":-9serverkey

Comment: If that's your real data, then you can't use this method. you need to clean your data first.

Comment: Yes the data need to clean.. is there any builtin regular expression available in spark sql to apply to just make this intermittent string to the valid or should use udf.. ?

Comment: @Adhi I added the step to clean the data. But you should better fix the source rather than doing it in spark.